# libuv timer callback in an UDP C-application fires randomly

Tags: c, matlab, sockets, timer, libuv

i use the libuv UDP functionality encapsulated in a DLL. It works, i can send and receive packets via callbacks. Now i need a functionality to stop my receive watcher after a certain time (e.g. when no clients are available). But when i set the timeout to 10 sec. the timer callback is randomly fired (e.g. 0,4,7,10 sec.). I tried to use two different loops for UDP and timer but no change. Is there a special calling convention for accurate timing?

My init funciton is:

```
void udp_app_init(...)
{
...
//some libuv UDP init-functions 
uv_timer_init(loop, &my_udp_timeout);
...
}
```

My UDP send function sends the actual packet and starts the UDP and timer watchers:

```
void udp_app_senddata(...)
{
...
uv_udp_send(...);
uv_timer_start(&my_udp_timeout, udp_timeout_action, 10000, 0);
uv_udp_recv_start(&recv_socket, alloc_buffer, vCallBack);
uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

The timer callback stops the timer watcher and (if no packets arrived) the UDP receive watcher:

```
void udp_timeout_action(...)
{
uv_timer_stop(handle);
if(uv_is_active((uv_handle_t*)&recv_socket))
    uv_udp_recv_stop(&recv_socket);
}
```